# connecting MySQL database to copied and pasted data directory

Tags: mysql, linux, database

I copied a database directory from the datadir (/var/lib/mysql/) of a MySQL instance running on a server to my local machine. Is it possible to put this database directory into my local MySQL datadir and access that database?

What I have done so far is copy the database directory like above, I log in to the MySQL and can see the database, I switch to it and can list all the tables. But when ever I try to query a table I get something like:

```
select * from users limit 1;
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'users' doesn't exist
```

Also from mysqldump:

```
mysqldump: Got error: 1146: Table 'very_first_table' doesn't exist when using LOCK TABLES
```

Is it possible to do what I am trying to do here?

Comment: Are you copying using `mysqldump` and inserting into your `local` database using `mysql -u -p database < dbfile.sql`?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with the linux paths used, but I know in Windows it was a simple matter of copying the schema directory from one server to another **for MyISAM tables**; for InnoDB tables it is not quite as simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I got it to work, bare in mind that my end goal was to get a database dump from the database. The mysql folder was extracted from a older virtual machine snapshot which could not be run at the moment, so I couldn't just log in to it and do a normal dump. Here is what I did:

1) I installed mysql on a fresh vm on my local machine

2) I shut down mysql with `service mysql stop`

3) I removed the existing /var/lib/mysql folder from the fresh install

4) I replaced it with the /var/lib/mysql folder that was removed from the old snapshot

5) I ran `chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql`

6) I restarted mysql with `service mysql start`

7) Then I checked if I could log in and query the tables, I could!

So I was able to run the dump after that.